# cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I log in with a user (not sys) from sql plus as in the first picture and run the trigger from oracle sql developer but it gives me error as in the second picture.

[image]

`ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS`

[image]

I'm using Oracle 12c and not sure whether my trigger code is exactly correct.  My purpose is to show a warning when someone tries adding same ogrenci_no (student_number). What can I do for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you granted the SYSDBA privilege to that user, then you are indirectly using the SYS account.  Here's a little video on how to create a simple user for storing your tables.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDJacg0NuLo

Now, onto your trigger.  You generally would never issue a rollback (or commit) in a trigger, because its potentially part of a larger transaction.  What you want to do is raise an error which will abandon the statement that fired trigger, eg

```
if :new.col = :old.col then
  raise_application_error(-20000,'You did not change the value');
end if;
```

But of course, this is not going to work in your case, because you are trapping an INSERT statement, so there is *no* 'old' value.  I think your intent here is not have any duplicates in the table...so you do not need (or want) a trigger for this, you want a unique constraint, eg

```
alter table MY_TABLE add constraint MY_TABLE_UQ unique ( ogrenci_no) ;
```

which will prevent duplicates from being allowed.